# How to specify a git-branch at runtime?

Tags: git

I would like to run code from a specific branch of my git repository while continue developing the code and making commits to another branch. How can I do that?

Comment: What language is it? Is it compiled? What kind of development environment? What does the workflow look like? Do you need the changes that you make to be visible in the instance that you run? (In that case chances are that you don't want to do this in the first place)

Comment: If you do need parallel branches, consider using another worktree https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/26/parallelize-development-git-worktrees/

Comment: What is the problem in checking out that specific branch and run the code?

Comment: Have you read any of the tutorials at GitHub? They cover many use cases like this.